# Get IP from sockadrr

Tags: sockets, struct, ip

As far as I know, a sockaddr structure consists of:

```
struct sockaddr 
{   
    unsigned short sa_family;  
    char sa_data[14];          
}; `
```

If I already have the structure data: how can I get the IP from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `struct sockaddr` to a specific subclass which depends on the family:

- If the family is `AF_UNIX`, cast the `struct sockaddr` to a `struct sockaddr_un`
- If the family is `AF_INET`, cast the `struct sockaddr` to a `struct sockaddr_in`
- If the family is `AF_INET6`, cast the `struct sockaddr` to a `struct sockaddr_in6`
- etc...

Once you have cast the structure to one of the latter types, you can get the address from that structure. Note that the format of addresses is different for each protocol, and so are the names and types of the fields that contain them. For example, if the family is `AF_UNIX` you can get a pathname from `sun_path` (and in this case there is no such thing as an IP address) whereas if the family is `AF_INET6` you can get an IP address and port number from `sin6_addr` and `sin6_port`, respectively.

Comment: @danvari, that's fair to say, since C does indeed not provide any syntax for classes, methods, etc... but I think it's appropriate to use OO terminology for OO concepts even if OO syntax is not used.